# Transforming function for reading txt files into one string to document logics

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nltk, python-os, countvectorizer

Have a bunch of .txt files in the folder. Here are two functions which are using for reading these files and saving them into a variable as one string:

```
s=(glob.glob("/Users/user/documents/folder/*.txt"))

def read_files(files):
    for filename in files:
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as file:
            yield file.read()

def read_files_as_string(files, separator='\n'):
    files_content = list(read_files(files=files))
    return separator.join(files_content)

results=read_files_as_string(s)
```

Now my idea to use sklearn's `CountVectorizer()` for getting n-grams from the text. But `CountVectorizer()` does not receive as input the string. So my question would be- how can I make the function for reading the files not to storing them into one string but store them using that logic: ['text1.txt', 'text2.txt', ..., 'textn.txt']

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have I understood correctly that you want the result to be like `["contents of text1.txt", "contents of text2.txt", …]`, not the filenames as your question shows?

Comment: fully correct. not the names but the contexts like you mentioned: ["contents of text1.txt", "contents of text2.txt", …]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read_files` already does almost all of what you want. You can call it directly and use `list` to convert it from a generator into a regular list:

```
results = list(read_files(s))
```